# C++ variable constructor method with constant constructor arguments

Tags: c++, class, constructor, function-pointers

I am trying to use function pointers in a class constructor so that I can select which function is used to construct an object of the class. I want to do this to be able to change the method of how the member variables in a class are determined with a same set of constructor arguments. I have been able to code this succesfully, as shown in following code, however I need to declare all individual functions that are pointed to as friends.

My question: Is there any way to declare a function with unknown name (i.e. only return type and a set of arguments is known) as a friend? I want this because in future development there may be new functions added, while the class remains the same and I do not want to add a new friend declaration for each new function.

Of course I am also open to other approaches to achieve my goal.

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
private:
    int var_1;
public:
    foo(void (*functionPtr)(foo*))
    {
        functionPtr(this);
    }
    ~foo(){}

    int get_var() {return var_1;}

    friend void function_1(foo*); // declare all unique
    friend void function_2(foo*); // functions as friends

    /*friend void (*functionPtr)(foo*); // this is what I want:
                                        // to declare all functions with
                                        // a specific return type and
                                        // specific arguments as a friend
                                        // of this class */
};

void function_1(foo* T)
{
    std::cout << "function 1" << std::endl;
    T->var_1 = 1;
}

void function_2(foo* T)
{
    std::cout << "function 2" << std::endl;
    T->var_1 = 2;
}

int main()
{
    foo F1(&function_1);
    std::cout << F1.get_var() << std::endl;

    foo F2(&function_2);
    std::cout << F2.get_var() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm too old and rusty to consider this in detail, but do study the *visitor* pattern.

Comment: "I want to do this to be able to..." - no you don't son. What you want to do is clearly define your requirements and then see which language feature correctly models it.

Comment: As Bathsheba noticed you might want to adopt a pattern for this. I'd recommend to look also at a factory pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will look in to them

Comment: As far I could understand both patterns: The factory pattern still requires  functions to be added to code that I want to leave unchanged. The visitor pattern seems promosing, but is quite elaborate to implement and complicated when comparing it to the answer of John Zwinck below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the parts you want to initialize into a separate place where they are considered public:

```
struct foovars
{
    int var_1;
};

class foo : foovars
{
public:
    foo(void (*functionPtr)(foovars*))
    {
        functionPtr(this);
    }
};

void function_1(foovars* T)
{
    std::cout << "function 1" << std::endl;
    T->var_1 = 1;
}
```

Now your member variable is just as private as it was before, from the perspective of code holding an instance of `class foo`.  But special functions which manage to receive a `foovars*` can modify its members.

Comment: @Sjonnie: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: If the variables have a public interface why aren't we just encapsulating them and passing them in using copy semantics? This will be clearer and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Static `class` functions will work better here:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int var_1;
public:
    foo(void (*functionPtr)(foo*))
    {
        functionPtr(this);
    }
    ~foo(){}

    int get_var() {return var_1;}

    static void function_1(foo*); // declare all unique
    static void function_2(foo*); // functions as friends

};

void foo::function_1(foo* T)
{
    std::cout << "function 1" << std::endl;
    T->var_1 = 1;
}

void foo::function_2(foo* T)
{
    std::cout << "function 2" << std::endl;
    T->var_1 = 2;
}


int main()
{
    foo F1(&foo::function_1);
    std::cout << F1.get_var() << std::endl;

    foo F2(&foo:function_2);
    std::cout << F2.get_var() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Since they are members of the class, no `friend` is needed, and they have full access to the class's `private` members.

Even better, the `static` functions can be `private`, and inaccessible outside of the class.

Comment: This requires modifying the class definition every time you want to add a new function.  The way I interpreted the question was that was not acceptable, else the `friend` approach would work.

Comment: You should not be encouraging this horrible anti-pattern. You'll be responsible for the next generation of garbage code.

Comment: As John said, this indeed adds more to the class that I want to remain unchanged

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use tag dispatching. It's (much) more maintainable and will result in more efficient code.

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
private:
    int var_1;
public:
    struct type1_type {}; static constexpr type1_type type1{};
    struct type2_type {}; static constexpr type2_type type2{};

    foo(type1_type)
    : var_1(1)
    {
        // initialisation for type 1 construction
    }

    foo(type2_type)
    : var_1(2)
    {
        // initialisation for type 2 construction
    }

    ~foo(){}

    int get_var() {return var_1;}


};

int main()
{
    foo F1(foo::type1);
    std::cout << F1.get_var() << std::endl;

    foo F2(foo::type2);
    std::cout << F2.get_var() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected result:

```
1
2
```

Comment: This requires the class itself to be changed when a new function is added, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid here.